# Counter not live

Tags: javascript, jquery-countdown

My following script works: but with one problem: it doesnt count down. 
It gives the right output (time now untill date) but doesnt update automatically.

Anyone nows whats wrong?

The main thing is this countdown timer works with server time (thats why the post, and time.php).

```
        <script>
var end = new Date('10/7/2013 7:0 PM');

var _second = 1000;
var _minute = _second * 60;
var _hour = _minute * 60;
var _day = _hour * 24;
var timer;

var now;
function startShowRemaining(strnow) {
now = new Date(strnow);
showRemaining();
}
function showRemaining() {
//var now = new Date(strnow);
    var distance = end - now;
    if (distance < 0) {

        clearInterval(timer);
        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = 'EXPIRED!';

        return;
    }
    var days = Math.floor(distance / _day);
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % _day) / _hour);
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % _hour) / _minute);
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % _minute) / _second);

    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = days + 'days ';
    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML += hours + 'hrs ';
    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML += minutes + 'mins ';
    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML += seconds + 'secs';
}

timer = setInterval(showRemaining, 1000);

function postRequest(strURL) {
var xmlHttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari, ...
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE
    var xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlHttp.open('POST', strURL, true);
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 
   'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
        startShowRemaining(xmlHttp.responseText);
    }
}
xmlHttp.send(strURL); }
postRequest('time.php');      
</script>
<div id="countdown"></div>
```

TIME.PHP:

```
print date("m/d/Y, G:i:s");
```

Comment: Why are you calling `showRemaining` in two places? You have `timer = setInterval(showRemaining, 1000);` and then also inside of `startShowRemaining`. You're also calling `clearInterval(timer);` inside of `showRemaining`, which would stop it after one time

Comment: @Ian: He only stops it once it's expired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are only polling the server time once. You call `showRemaining` again and again, but the `now` time will never change, therefor the output will never change.

If you need to use server time, you need to send the request you are sending in `postRequest` everytime `showRemaining` is called and use it for `now`:

*Some of this post was deleted since it was wrong*

You can find an example in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7CbFy/8/), where I replaced the contents of `postRequest` with a stub to use the client time instead of making an Ajax call (since I don't have access to your `time.php`).

Of course, repeated server requests like that are quite inefficient, so you really should consider using the client's clock. You could also consider using the server time once and then use the Javascript clock to add to that time.

Comment: hello thanx for your comment dont get it really, can you give me an examplle>

Comment: I added a jsfiddle. By the way, looking at your other questions, please make use of SO's voting system and accepting answers, otherwise you may find people less willing to help you, plus it will help other people coming across this question.

Comment: GAH!! You beat me in providing an answer.. and mines looked really close to yours.. http://jsfiddle.net/GCaSK/

Comment: BUt in the jsfiddle, you use client time again, not the server time thats the difficulty

Comment: both answers are using CLIENT TIME not server time. Sorry, thats the whole difficulty

Comment: Please read my answer again more carefully. I told you I was stubbing the server call with client time. If you just plug your old `postRequest` back in with the adjustment I described in my post, it will be the way you want it to be.

Comment: Ok final question, what do i need to do to make it work then?

Comment: I described that in detail in my post and comments. I do require you to try to understand what I say. If you want someone to just do it for you so you can copy it, Stackoverflow is not the right place for you.

Comment: and really like you to help, but when time = expired he doesnt show the message

Comment: It shows the message just fine. If it doesn't for you, please tell us what browser you are using. Also, as for making it work for you, try to follow the steps I described. If you're stuck at some point, describe what you don't understand and what you have got so far.

Comment: Ok now its using servertime, but when time = past, then the message EXPERID! is not showing, i am using chrome

Comment: Does it also not work if you use the fiddle I provided (with client-time stub)? I am using Chrome as well and it works for me just fine. You should try debugging it to see where it goes wrong (maybe `distance` never falls below 0).

Comment: Sorry men, its not using servertime, only client time. I read carefully what you wrote, but i dont get the point what i need to change on your jsfiddle to make it work (using server time)

Comment: I'll try to be more detailed: Take the code from my fiddle. Then replace `postRequest` with your method (that uses server-time). Finally, replace the three lines I mentioned in my post so that `postRequest` returns the response instead of calling `startShowRemaining` (which does not exist anymore anyway).

Comment: Ok. 1 Taking your code is 100%  Second step: replacing postrequest with my method (Which lines are those in my script?)

Comment: The lines describing the function `postRequest`. You do know what a function is, right?

Comment: yes i do:P but when i take those lines i get: NaNdays NaNhrs NaNmins NaNsecs
 as output. So i guess i'm taking the wrong lines

Comment: You will get `NaN`s as long as you haven't finished the last step (returning instead of calling `startShowRemaining`)

Comment: yeah, then the output is blanco

Comment: Can you upload what you have got now to a jsfiddle and give us the link?

Comment: You didn't do the last step yet.

Comment: No, not really. For some reason, you replaced too much with your old code. Have a look at what function I call in `setInterval` and what function you call there. The same goes for the line after that, plus you unneccesarily call `postRequest` right before the `setInterval` call.

Comment: Ok, can you please give me the code, i wont copy paste it without looking, but i dont get it. Maybe i'm to stupid, but when i see it, i can figure out what you mean, and taking a carefull look. Right now i'm stucked.

Comment: Just find the `setInterval` call all the way on the bottom and compare what you have there with what I have. I'm sure you'll see the difference.

Comment: ok i start from the beginnen. I copied your code from jsfiddle. 
After that i need to  replace postRequest with my method (that uses server-time).

Comment: I think those lines are: 
function postRequest(strURL) {
var xmlHttp;

xmlHttp.send(strURL); }

Comment: Okay, I fixed the mistake now. You called `setInterval(postRequest, 1000);`, but it should've been `setInterval(showRemaining, 1000)`. Now go on and do the last step from here, that's really all the code I'll serve you since you literally only need to replace one line now: http://jsfiddle.net/7CbFy/3/

Comment: Did you see my last comment?

Comment: Thanks for helping. I see your last comment. You've uploaded a new version onto jsfiddle. Now i need to make one more replacement? (My english is not very good, thats also why i have difficulty understanding) what is the last instruction?

Comment: The last instruction is to return the response text instead of calling `startShowRemaining` inside `postRequest`. My original answer even contains what it has to look like afterwards.

Comment: Yes, like that. This should work now. Please don't forget voting and marking the answer as accepted if it solved your problem.

Comment: mmm doesnt work still says: Nan:Nan:Nan etc. not only at JSfiddle, but also on webpage

Comment: Oh my. Okay, yes. Sorry, this time it was my fault. The problem remaining is a little bit more tricky, this I will fix for you. Just hold on.

Comment: Try this one now. I also took the chance to clean some of your code up. http://jsfiddle.net/7CbFy/5/

Comment: NaNdays NaNhrs NaNmins NaNsec still :S And time.php is gone?